# Prevent setup project from uninstalling busy service

Tags: windows-services, setup-project, uninstallation

How do I prevent my setup project from uninstalling my Windows service while it is performing a lengthy work routine?

Ideally, MSI should report that the "Service is currently busy and cannot be uninstalled."

How to create a condition for the installer to check if the service is busy and fail the installation?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use an [Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) class for your application.  You could override the [OnBeforeUninstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.onafteruninstall.aspx) method so that it looks to see if the process is running, and then waits for it to stop before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to the one YWE posted is to create a custom action inside a DLL and run it when the uninstall process starts. In the custom action you could interrogate the service to check it's status and if it's busy fail the install with a relevant message for the user.

[Walkthrough: Creating a custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)